# Why are protons in the same position in 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene magnetically different?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, terminology

Protons in *ortho* positions towards the nitro group are said to be magnetically different, even though they're chemically equivalent. Same goes for protons *ortho* towards the chlorine. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3):

The hunch lies in the definition of magnetic equivalence:

> For two protons to be magnetically equivalent they not only have to have the same chemical shift, but *they must also each have the same $J$ coupling* to other magnetic nuclei in the molecule.

(Quoted from [Hans Reich’s NMR course online syllabus](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-08-symmetry.htm#05-hmr-08-symmetry-magnequiv); emphasis present in the original.)

What does that mean for our specific example? Compare the molecule we have in figure 1 below.

[image]
**Figure 1:** 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene with labelled protons.

Needless to say as you already figured that $\ce{H^1}$ and $\ce{H^3}$ are *chemically* equivalent (one is transformed into the other by $C_2$<sup>‡</sup>) meaning that they will display the same chemical shift; likewise for $\ce{H^2}$ and $\ce{H^4}$.

However, for magnetic equivalence we need to consider their coupling constants to each other. If $\ce{H^1}$ and $\ce{H^3}$ are *magnetically* equivalent, then $J_{\ce{H^1 H^2}} \overset{!}{=} J_{\ce{H^3 H^2}}$. But, $J_{\ce{H^1 H^2}}$ is an *ortho* coupling with a value of $J \approx 7~\mathrm{Hz}$ while $J_{\ce{H^3 H^2}}$ is a *para* coupling with $J \approx 0~\mathrm{Hz}$.

Thus we can easily see that $J_{\ce{H^1 H^2}} \ne J_{\ce{H^3 H^2}}$ and therefore the nuclei $\ce{H^1}$ and $\ce{H^3}$ are **magnetically non-equivalent.**

The same argument can be made for $\ce{H^2}$ and $\ce{H^4}$.

---

‡: They are also transformed into each other by the $\sigma_{\mathrm{v}1}$ plane. However, planes of symmetry create enantiotopic protons while rotations create isotopic ones. In this case — a non-chiral environment and a non-chiral solvent — enantiotopic protons cannot be distinguished and give a common signal, and thus are sometimes incorrectly called chemically equivalent. The argument is not of relevance here though, since the $C_2$ axis renders the protons isotopic thus equivalent.

Comment: Nice answer! One small point, I agree that $\ce{H^1}$ and $\ce{H^3}$ are *chemically* equivalent due to the presence of the $C_2$ axis; if only the $\sigma_{\mathrm{v}1}$ plane existed wouldn't the two protons be enantiotopic instead of equivalent?

Comment: It isn't a "hunch" but a "twist" or "quirk" in the definition. You need to also explain that if the two chemically equivalent H atoms were also magnetically equivalent then there would be just two peaks in the H NMR where each peak was for two protons. Rather the observed spectra is for two sets of peaks where each set has a value of two and each set is split into multiple lines. $ce{H^1}$ and $ce{H^3}$ are each contribute half in each of the multiple peaks in one of the sets.

Comment: @MaxW About that first word, feel free to edit in a better one. About the rest: I disagree. It’s not like we could say one half of the peak is $\ce{H^1}$ and the other half $\ce{H^3}$. Those two signals are overlaid together into a single peak much like the three protons of a methyl group give a single peak.

Comment: @Jan  Not to belabor the point, but two items are either equivalent, enantiotopic or distereotopic.  In your 1-iodobutane example the proton pairs on the same carbon are enatiotopic, they are not equivalent.  In a chiral solvent they could display different chemical shifts and different reactivities.

Comment: @ron Thinking about it again, you are correct. I hope I have re-edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: I'm confused at this point. A NMR can be found here. http://www.hanhonggroup.com/nmr/nmr_en/RB03060011.html The multiplet at 8.180 is for two H atoms and the multiplet at 7.528 is for two H atoms. Within each peak of the multiplet at 7.528 each "B" hydrogen contributes half to each peak. (I don't understand why the multiplet is split into 9 peaks, or why the 8.180 multiplet is split into 11 peaks.)

Comment: @MaxW If you take a macroscopic look at that spectrum, I see a pair of doublets. Each doublet is then further (and complexly) split as all aromatic signals are. At least two minor peaks around each main peak should be $\ce{^{13}C}$ satellites, too.